Visual Studio -- LINK : fatal error LNK1117: syntax error in option ''
Getting this error in Visual Studio
LINK : fatal error LNK1117: syntax error in option ''

Linker error coming in Visual studio.. which property settings to check ?
In my linker input i have following files to link
vfw32.lib
glew32.lib
glfw3.lib
zlibd.lib
libjasperd.lib
libpngd.lib
libtiffd.lib
libjpegd.lib
IlmImfd.lib
opengl32.lib
opencv_core249d.lib
opencv_calib3d249d.lib
opencv_highgui249d.lib
opencv_imgproc249d.lib




You show only libraries, but what is your linker's complete command line (Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Command Line)?
